# Worthwhile info in comment was deleted, why?

Tags: discussion

I [posted a question here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21217/alternatives-for-kidney-disease-food) some time ago.

I noticed today that some of the comments were deleted. More specifically, the comment involved linking to a side outside of SE with a lot of valuable information for me, as the owner of a cat with CKD. (I had found the site before asking my question and I still have the site, that's not an issue).

I'm mostly wondering why was the comment deleted? Was it because it provided medical information? Because it pointed to a different resource than SE? Something else?

Answer (score 5):

I deleted the comments on your question. I regularly remove comments from posts that make the question look cluttered, have run their course (no longer needed) or are not a good use of comments.

The ['Comment Everywhere'](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege says:

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

This means that generally, you won't want to rely on a comment being left for a long time on your question. In the `'When shouldn't I comment'` section it says:

> Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);

---

Specifically for the post you mentioned:

The [first comment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21217/alternatives-for-kidney-disease-food#comment28841_21217) requested a clarification:

> Did you ask your vet for possible alternatives?

The reply should have been edited into the question (which I have now done). Both of these were deleted because they had now run their course. I would normally edit the comments into the question so I must have missed that step. Apologies if this caused you inconvenience.

The [next comment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21217/alternatives-for-kidney-disease-food#comment28879_21217) seems a little confused about link only answers. A link only answer is when only a link is posted. In this case, the relevant information [could have been referenced from the source link](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and posted as an answer. I frequently remove comments that answer the question in the comments because they [bypass the voting system](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

I'll clear up the comments in a few days again so you may want to take note of the link posted there. If anything else is still unclear, please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.